# Can I remove one ubuntu without touching the other?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, uninstall

I have ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 lts on the same notebook. I want to get rid of ubuntu 14.04. Can I do it without remove ubuntu 14.04 without removing ubuntu 12.04.4?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have them on different partitions. Just use `gparted` to clear the partition with 12.04 and you should be good to go. If they're not on separate partitions, it will be more complex.

Comment: I selected the "Install ubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside with ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS"

Comment: @Jatttt What musher is saying is install gparted from the software centre, and then open it. As long as you know which is which, you can delete the 14.04 partition, and it will be removed.